# How to not change the select tag text on change of option

Tags: reactjs

I don't want the tag to change to cat/dog/rat after one of those are chosen, I want the text of the select tag to remain at "Pick a Pet" even while clicking the other options.

```
<select defaultValue={"DEFAULT"}>
    <option value="DEFAULT"> Pick a Pet </option>
    <option value="cat"> cat </option>
    <option value="dog"> dog </option>
    <option value="rat"> rat </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a onChange handler on select to set pet, and at select instead of set defaultValue set value instead:

```
const Select = () => {


    const [pet, setPet] = useState(null)
    
    const changeHandler = e => {
      if(e.target.value) setPet(e.target.value)
    }
    
return (
  <select value={''} onChange={changeHandler} >
  <option value=""> Pick a Pet </option>
  <option value="cat"> cat </option>
  <option value="dog"> dog </option>
  <option value="rat"> rat </option>
  </select>
)
}
```

Comment: I dont want to disable any options, I just want the text of the select tag to always remain at "Pick a Pet" even when clicking the other options

Comment: I edited. set `value` at select instead of `defaultValue` while you control state through react